# How to scraping there are not class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

How to scrap data when there are not any class I know way using ID,Class using `document.getElementsByClassName`.

```html
<tr id="overview-summary-current">
   <th scope="row">
      <span class="edit-tools">
      <a href="#background-experience" class="edit-section" id="control_gen_5">Edit experience
      </a>
      </span>
      <a href="#background-experience" data-trk="prof-0-ovw-curr_pos">Current</a>
   </th>
   <td>
      <ol>
         <li>
            <strong>
            <a href="/company/10097785?trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos" dir="auto">SNT Solutions rajkot</a>
            </strong>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want `SNT Solutions rajkot` how to get that value in variable using JavaScript.

`trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos` is unique in webpage

Comment: With jQuery/Cheerio it would be easy : `$("a[href^='/company'"]).text()`, but in pure javascript it's a pain. You have to select all `a` tags, then filter them and stuff.

Comment: any way to using pure JavaScript @JeremyThille

Comment: Well, if you're scraping, it means you're running javascript server-side, so you're using Node (or there's something I'm missing). So just do `npm install cheerio` and enjoy server-side jQuery :) Why bother?

Comment: Are you asking for something like this:  document.querySelectorAll("a[href]").  That gives all 'a' tags that have an href attribute then you can loop through that array.

Comment: @JeremyThille no I am not use JavaScript it's client side (actually that code for chrome extensions)  also `trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos` is unique in web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got simple solution for that

```js
var a1 = document.querySelector('a[href$="trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos"]').text;
console.log('Data is  :::::'+a1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way(pure js):

```
var linksWithoutClass = document.querySelectorAll('#overview-summary-current a'); // return nodeList iterrator

var linksArray = [].slice.call(linksWithoutClass); // create array from Nodelist

linksArray.filter( function(link){ // filter list to get <a> without any class
  return link.classList.length === 0;
});
```

Comment: I want pure JS or jQuery code not other @JulesGoullee

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML

    `linksArray.forEach( function(linksNode){
        console.log(linksNode.innerHTML);
    });`

Comment: `trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos` is unique in web page @JulesGoullee

Comment: Simply use: `var linkWithoutClassContent = document.querySelectorAll('#overview-summary-current a').find( function(link){ return link.classList.length === 0}).innerHTML;`
Work only if first link without class is your target

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114368/discussion-between-divyesh-kanzariya-and-jules-goullee).